# Nancy request tracing does not show anything

Tags: nancy

After many trials, I can't seem to get Nancy's Diagnostic Tracing to show anything beyond a set of empty white boxes. It appears one box per browser session. Yet the boxes never include any information.

Per the [diagnostics page](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Diagnostics) I've added a diagnostics password and set

`StaticConfiguration.EnableRequestTracing = true;`

I expected there to be at some sort of default tracing out of the box, but just in case I made a call to

```
this.Context.Trace.TraceLog.WriteLog(x => x.AppendLine("What's ip?"));
```

in one of my modules, and confirmed said module route was getting called. Still no indication there was tracing going on.

We're running NancyFx version 1.45 in a framework 4.7.1 app. Any suggestions on why this could be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Enable tracing and diagnostics by using a custom bootstrapper.

For NancyFx v1:

```
NancyOptions options = new NancyOptions
{
    Bootstrapper = new CustomBootstrapper()
};
app.UseNancy(options);

public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

        StaticConfiguration.DisableErrorTraces = false;
        StaticConfiguration.EnableRequestTracing = true;
        if (!StaticConfiguration.EnableRequestTracing)
        {
            DiagnosticsHook.Disable(pipelines);
        }
    }

    protected override DiagnosticsConfiguration DiagnosticsConfiguration => new DiagnosticsConfiguration() { Enabled = true, Password = @"A2\6mVtH/XRT\p,B" };
}
```

For NancyFx v2:

```
NancyOptions options = new NancyOptions
{
    Bootstrapper = new CustomBootstrapper()
};
app.UseNancy(options);

public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    public override void Configure(INancyEnvironment environment)
    {
        environment.Diagnostics(
            enabled: true,
            password: @"A2\6mVtH/XRT\p,B");

        environment.Tracing(
            enabled: true,
            displayErrorTraces: true);
    }
}
```